# How can I configure apache to use php to create a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I want clients to be able to include one of my javascript files on their site like this:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/blah.js" ></script>
```

But I want to actually use php to dynamically create the javascript file/response (I don't want blah.js to actually exist on my server).  I am running ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2.4.7.  blah.js is the only file I want my server to act on like this.  In my php I will check the IP address and create the javascript file/response based on the client site.  I want any other javascript file request to act as normal.

Can I use .htaccess to override the directory to have any request for blah.js to be handled by php?

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of 'routing' http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/....

Answer (score 2):

Use rewrite in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blah\.js /blah.php [L]
```

When you will call /blah.js, it will be redirected to blah.php

Comment: I tried this, but I get "403 forbidden" response.  I also tried redirecting to the same file (blah.js -> blah.js) as a test, but again I get a "403" response.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .htaccess auto_prepend_file directive to prepend .php file before any of Your other php files come into play, and than use that prepended script to generate whatever You might need.

In Your .htaccess file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/my/loc/to/php/file.php"
```

There is also `auto_append_file` which will pull particular script just after last one manually included by You or application, and do the job after all content is generated, before headers are sent to the client.

Note that `php_value` directives are not enabled on each shared hosting setup.